# Reactjs - Adding check all/uncheck all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm new and learning ReactJS and I'm trying to add a checkbox that will check/uncheck all of my other checkboxes. When I click on the "All" checkbox, the screen for the GUI goes white. The other checkboxes work as normal and are generated and assigned to data that is read from a DB based on data name. The handleAllToggle code is based on one that I found else where on here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wn09v3x4y7?file=/src/index.js

Please help.

```
import toggleItemLayer

this.state = {checkAll: true,
   itemList: [],
   fruitOrNot: new Map(),
   checkedItems: new Map()}

getItemList() {
   let url = myDbUrl;
   fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(items => {
         this.setState({ itemList: items })
         for (let i = 0; i < this.state.itemList.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.itemList[i].name === 'Fruit') {
               this.setState({ fruitOrNot: this.state.fruitOrNot.set(this.state.itemList[i].name, 'Fruit') })
            } else {
               this.setState({ fruitOrNot: this.state.fruitOrNot.set(this.state.itemList[i].name, 'Not') })
            }
      })
      .catch(error => {
         console.log(error)
      });
}

handleItemToggle = async (event) => {
   let isChecked = event.target.checked;
   let item = event.target.value;
   this.setState({ checkedItems: this.state.checkedItem.set(item, isChecked) })
   
   let index = this.state.itemList.findIndex(element => element.name === item)
   await toggleItemLayer(this.sate.itemList[index], isChecked)
}

handleAllToggle = event => {
   let checkedItems = this.state.checkedItems;

   checkedItems.forEach(checkedItem => (checkedItem.isChecked = event.target.checked));
   this.setState({ checkedItems: checkedItems });
}

render() {
   return (
      <tr>
         <td style={{ paddingRight: '1em' }}><input
         type="checkbox"
         value="checkAll"
         defaultChecked={this.state.checkAll}
         checked={this.state.checkedSource}
         onChange={this.handleAllToggle}
         /></td>
         All
      </tr>

      this.state.itemList.map((item, index) => (
         <tr key={item.name}>
            <td style={{ paddingRight: '1em' }}><input
               type="checkbox"
               id={index}
               value={item.name}
               onChange={this.handleItemToggle}
               checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.name) === undefined ? true : this.state.checkedItems.get(item.name)}
            /></td>

        {/*additional properties code*/}

         </tr>   
   )
}
```

***EDIT:***

I have figured it out after doing more research. Since I'm still new, I had to research what most of the individual code was doing. Here is the changes I made:

**Getting the fruits from the database. Instead of just filling the fruitList, I also filled the checkedItems map object.**

```
getItemList() {
   let url = myDbUrl;
   fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(items => {
         this.setState({ itemList: items })
         for (let i = 0; i < this.state.itemList.length; i++) {
            this.state.checkedItems.set(this.state.itemList[i].name, true)
            if (this.state.itemList[i].name === 'Fruit') {
               this.setState({ fruitOrNot: this.state.fruitOrNot.set(this.state.itemList[i].name, 'Fruit') })
            } else {
               this.setState({ fruitOrNot: this.state.fruitOrNot.set(this.state.itemList[i].name, 'Not') })
            }
      })
      .catch(error => {
         console.log(error)
      });
}
```

**Changes to handleAllToggle**

```
handleAllToggle = event => {
   let checkedItems = this.state.checkedItems;
   let isChecked = event.target.checked;
   let myCheckedVal = [...this.state.checkedItems.values()];
   let myKeys = [...this.state.checkedItems.keys()];

   for(let i = 0; i < myKeys.length; i++) {
      myCheckedVal = isChecked;
      this.setState({checkedSource: checkedSources.set(myKeys[i], myCheckedVal[i])});
   }
}
```

**My created checkbox**

```
render() {
   return (
      <tr>
         <td style={{ paddingRight: '1em' }}><input
         type="checkbox"
         defaultChecked={this.state.checkAll}
         onChange={this.handleAllToggle}
         /></td>
         All
      </tr>

      this.state.itemList.map((item, index) => (
         <tr key={item.name}>
            <td style={{ paddingRight: '1em' }}><input
               type="checkbox"
               id={index}
               value={item.name}
               onChange={this.handleItemToggle}
               checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.name)}
            /></td>

        {/*additional properties code*/}

         </tr>   
   )
}
```

I hope this helps someone who is stuck in a similar situation. Also, if there is a better way of doing this, please let me know. I'm excited to keep learning.

Comment: It would be helpful to share the error that was given to you in your console.

Comment: That's the thing, the console doesn't display any errors. At start up it shows the checkboxes, but when I click on the "All" checkbox, the show screen goes white. Nothing is displayed in the console.

Comment: I found the error. The console states that the checkedItem.isChecked is not defined